# How To fix the error returned by dev_appserver.py

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web, localhost

Please Help!
It's my first project using app engine. I've created the app with the required files. But when I try starting the server in the cloud sdk cmd (and other cmd programs) it returns an error relating to Method Resolution Order (MRO).

I tried running the dev_appserver.py from both the folder containing the gcloud skd (while supplying the application forlder) and the application folder (c:\path-to-app>dev_appserver.py)
Please see the error below:

```
D:\AMINU BISHIR\AMINU BISHIR\PROGRAMMING\Full Stack Web\Programs\my_app_engine>dev_appserver.py .
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sadarwa\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\dev_appserver.py", line 14, in <module>
    from bootstrapping import bootstrapping
  File "C:\Users\Sadarwa\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\bootstrapping\bootstrapping.py", line 46, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core.updater import update_manager
  File "C:\Users\Sadarwa\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\updater\update_manager.py", line 35, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core import yaml
  File "C:\Users\Sadarwa\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\yaml.py", line 29, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core import yaml_location_value
  File "C:\Users\Sadarwa\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\yaml_location_value.py", line 39, in <module>
    from ruamel import yaml
  File "C:\Users\Sadarwa\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\ruamel\yaml\__init__.py", line 85, in <module>
    from ruamel.yaml.main import *  # NOQA
  File "C:\Users\Sadarwa\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\ruamel\yaml\main.py", line 19, in <module>
    from ruamel.yaml.loader import BaseLoader, SafeLoader, Loader, RoundTripLoader  # NOQA
  File "C:\Users\Sadarwa\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\ruamel\yaml\loader.py", line 10, in <module>
    from ruamel.yaml.constructor import (
  File "C:\Users\Sadarwa\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\ruamel\yaml\constructor.py", line 21, in <module>
    from ruamel.yaml.comments import *                               # NOQA
  File "C:\Users\Sadarwa\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\ruamel\yaml\comments.py", line 642, in <module>
    class CommentedMap(MutableMapping, ordereddict, CommentedBase):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\abc.py", line 86, in __new__
    cls = super(ABCMeta, mcls).__new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace)
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases ordereddict, MutableMapping, CommentedBase
```

Comment: it's the dev_appserver.py file that i'm trying to run

Comment: @rdas all this code is in the SDK, there's no user code in the traceback.

Comment: Are you running the latest version of the SDK?  Are you able to try downgrading (or upgrading) the SDK App Engine components?

Comment: @snakecharmerb yes it's the latest version. I downloaded it from the google official cloud website

Comment: On the assumption that Google have introduced a bug in the latest version I'd suggest [downgrading](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/components/update) to a previous version (the update command lets you downgrade to a specific version).  If downgrading a couple of times doesn't fix it then that suggests there might be something wrong with your installation.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED!**

Thank you all for responding!
This is what worked for me:
1. After carefully looking at the logs from App Engine launcher, I discover that the error actually comes from a python file (which is part of the python installation package)
2. I downloaded the latest version of the python 2 (2.7.15) and installed it
3. After installation, I was able to solve the problem!
Cheers and thank you all!

Comment: I'm seeing this same issue on a new install (new hard disk), and had downloaded 2.7.16. Reinstalling 2.7.15 fixed it.... Not sure if it's just 2.7.16 is broken somehow, or if the initial installation might have been corrupt.